# CakePHP 2.0 inner join and create view

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new in Cakephp 2.0, but I want to make a view of two tables with Inner Join.
I have the following tables tables:

**hpsas with records: id, ciname, location, status**

**ldaps with records: id, ciname, status**

The query I would do in MySQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM hpsas INNER JOIN ldaps ON hpsas.ciname = ldaps.ciname;
```

Which syntax do I have to use in whether the models, the controller or the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'ldaps',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'hpsas.ciname = ldaps.ciname',
        )
    )
);

$this->Hpsa->find('all', $options);
```

See Cake book section on associations for more details: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Comment: Hi All thnx for your reply. When I use "$options['joins'] = array(" I get the following error:Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hpsas.ciname' in 'on clause'

Did I Forgot something? What is wrong? Thnx again for all replies.

Comment: Set debug to 2 (in core.php) and check what the full SQL statement looks like.  (and I'm assuming you actually have a column "ciname" in your "hpsas" table?)

Comment: Hi Costa, thank you very much for your reply, and yes I have column "ciname" in "hpsas" table. The debug message I get is: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hpsas.ciname' in 'on clause' SQL Query: SELECT `Hpsa`.`ciname`, `Hpsa`.`locatie`, `Hpsa`.`status` FROM `cmdb`.`hpsas` AS `Hpsa` inner JOIN `cmdb`.`ldaps` ON (`hpsas`.`ciname` = `ldaps`.`ciname`) WHERE 1 = 1  Thnx for your reply!

Comment: Try changing the 'conditions' value to use the Cake table names. `'Hpsas.ciname = Ldaps.ciname'`

Comment: Hi Costa, it's working well, but I only see results of the hpsas table, not the results of ldaps table.

Comment: There are too many variables to debug this over SO. Via PHPMyadmin, write up a query manually to get the results you want.  Then compare that query to the query Cake generates.  That will give you some clues on what to change in the Cake code.

Answer (score 0):

follow the activeRecord model i think you should define a relationship in the model to avoid running complex queries everytime you need records from this models. you will need to stick to cake's conventions tho and that means you will have 3 models(most possibly)

```
class cinema extends AppModel{

    hasMany = array(hpsas,idaps);
}
class hpsas extends AppModel{

     belongsTo = array(cinema)
}
class idap extends AppModel{
 belongsTo = array(cinema)
}
```

with recursive set at above 2 or three one simple query to any one of the models will give you all the data you want(cake magic).